# How to multiply two tf.Variable type arrays with shape (2,2) and (2,)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, tensorflow

I was trying to convert the code

```
import numpy as np
W_np = np.ones((2,2))
x_np = np.array([1,0])
print(W_np @ x_np)

output: array([1., 1.])
```

into TensorFlow equivalent

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(2,2)), name="W", dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.Variable(np.array([1,0]), name = 'x', dtype=tf.float32)
W @ x
```

but got  an error message

```
InvalidArgumentError: In[1] is not a matrix. Instead it has shape [2] [Op:MatMul] name: matmul/
```

How to solve it?

Comment: The `numpy` `matmul` has special handling for 1d arrays (your (2,) shape).  See its docs.  The `tensorflow` version might not - again check its docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the next should work:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

tf.enable_eager_execution()
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(2,2)), name="W", dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.Variable(np.array([1,0]), name = 'x', dtype=tf.float32)
res =tf.linalg.matmul(W, tf.expand_dims(x, 0), transpose_b=True)
print(res)
# tf.Tensor([[1.] [1.]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)

# or slightly different way
res =tf.linalg.matmul(tf.expand_dims(x, 0), W)
res = tf.squeeze(res)
print(res)
# tf.Tensor([1. 1.], shape=(2,), dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use reshape():

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
W = tf.Variable(tf.ones(shape=(2,2)), name="W", dtype=tf.float32)
x = tf.Variable(np.array([1,0]).reshape(-1,1), name = 'x', dtype=tf.float32)
res = tf.matmul(W,x)
print(res)
```

Output:

```
tf.Tensor([[1.]
           [1.]], shape=(2, 1), dtype=float32)
```